# After the command sudo -i gedit /var/lib/dkpg/status. What should I do with this file to fix dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, synaptic

When I'm trying to install synaptic and many other applications Dependencies exists. I have done

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

but these all are not working.

What should I do? I just want to install synaptic.

[image]

```
apt-cache policy synaptic libept1.4.12 libgtk2-perl rarian-compat 
synaptic: 
  Installed: (none) 
  Candidate: 0.81.1ubuntu1 
  Version table: 
 *** 0.81.1ubuntu1 0 
          500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/universe amd64 
Packages 
libept1.4.12: 
  Installed: (none) 
  Candidate: (none) 
  Version table: 
libgtk2-perl: 
  Installed: (none) 
  Candidate: (none) 
  Version table: 
rarian-compat: 
  Installed: (none) 
  Candidate: (none) 
  Version table:

sudo apt-get install --simulate libept1.4.12 
[sudo] password for mohammad786: 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done 
Package libept1.4.12 is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted,  
or is only available from another source 
E: Package 'libept1.4.12' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please add more details on the error messages you get, and also what the reason was for this. You may find these posts helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa and http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy synaptic libept1.4.12 libgtk2-perl rarian-compat` and `apt-get install --simulate libept1.4.12`?

Comment: mohammad786@786:~$ apt-cache policy synaptic libept1.4.12 libgtk2-perl rarian-compat

synaptic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.81.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.81.1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
libept1.4.12:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libgtk2-perl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
rarian-compat:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

Comment: mohammad786@786:~$ sudo apt-get install --simulate libept1.4.12
[sudo] password for mohammad786: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libept1.4.12 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libept1.4.12' has no installation candidate

Comment: @daud_config, [edit] the question and the output of commands there. It is hard to read from comments , and important info should be added the question.